# How do I scroll an element to a specific height of a page in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm making a website with react typescript and tailwind and in it, there is a vertical list of the days of the month. The idea is that when you click on a day, it scrolls to the visible part of the div, that is 24rem under the top.

I have this function to scroll the selected day to the top of the page, but I actually need it to scroll 24rem below the top

```js
useEffect(() => {
  // Scroll to the selected day when the component mounts or when the selected date changes
  if (scrollRef.current) {
    const selectedDayElement = scrollRef.current.querySelector(".selected-day");
    if (selectedDayElement) {
      selectedDayElement.scrollIntoView({
        behavior: "smooth",
        block: "start",
      });

      scrollRef.current.scrollTop;
    }
  }
}, [value]);
```

I tried 'block: "center"' and 'nearest' but I need a more specific position. Chat GPT suggested some things using an offset property but none of them seemed to have any effects.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use refs here.

Just use `window.scrollTo(0, 24rem)` inside the effect hook.

Comment: I think I do need the ref actually. I just noticed that I wasn't very clear on my question, sorry about that. The context is that I have a list of the days of the month on a vertical row, and when I click on a specific day, It should go to the top of the visible part of the div, that is 24rem below the top of the page.

Answer (score 0):

I found something on the CSS that solved my problem. I'm using tailwind CSS so what worked for me was using "scroll-mt-[24rem]" on the element that's being scrolled. In pure CSS it would be "scroll-margin-top: 24rem. This makes the scroll function consider the margin, with the defined value.